# How to return a static instance in subclass type

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I am currently two class. Response with a simple attribute "responseCode". Response has a static instance (A simple response when it is KO).

I have also a class DetailResponse which is a subclass of my class Response.

What I would do is to be able to return an object of type DetailResponse using my static variable KO_RESPONSE in Response class. Is there a way to do it simply ?

My super class Response :

```
public class Response {
    public static final Response KO_RESPONSE = new A(ReturnCode.KO);

    public ReturnCode responseCode;
    public String comment;

    public Response () {};
    public Response (ReturnCode responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public static enum ReturnCode {
        OK,
        KO;
    }
}
```

My subclass DetailResponse which extends Response :

```
public class DetailResponse extends Response {
    public String otherField;
}
```

BuisinessService class :

```
public BuisinessService {
    public DetailResponse sendRequest() {
        String status = sendRequest() // Do something
        if(status.equals("KO")) {
            return Response.KO_RESPONSE; // What I would do but doesn't work because Response is the super class of DetailResponse
        } else {
            DetailResponse detail = new DetailResponse(ReturnCode.OK);
            detail.comment = "comment";
            detail.otherField = "somethingCool";
            return detail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just return a new instance of `DetailResponse` with the appropriate return code and no additional data? You can't use a static field and change its type at runtime, if you want to use static fields (or static factory methods) you'd have to provide one for each type and select accordingly.

Comment: Do you need to have the `Response.KO_RESPONSE` ever be a (non-Detail) `Response`? Or will it always be of type `DetailResponse`?

Comment: @Thomas I guess you're right. I was looking to do something easily readable. I think it may possible to do something with generic type and static factory, but it will still be more complex than a simple constructor.

Comment: @bradimus Yes it will be a DetailResponse.

Comment: Then either go with what @Thomas suggested or move the static instance to the child class.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override `static` variables, Java doesn't allow this. Instead you can implement below pattern to get instances of your base and child class. Here is an example:

```
    public class Response {
     public static Response getInstance(){
      return new Response(<args>);
     }
    }

    public class DetailedResponse extends Response {
     public static DetailedResponse getInstance(){
      return new DetailedResponse(<args>);
     }
    }
```

Finally the Business Class can be implemented as below:

```
public BuisinessService {
    public DetailResponse sendRequest() {
        String status = sendRequest() // Do something
        if(status.equals("KO")) {
            return DetailResponse.getInstance(); // What I would do but doesn't work because Response is the super class of DetailResponse
        } else {
            DetailResponse detail = new DetailResponse(ReturnCode.OK);
            detail.comment = "comment";
            detail.otherField = "somethingCool";
            return detail;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you return a new instance every time `getInstance()`, you don't have a singleton.

Comment: Yes, we won't be calling it singleton. Though this satisfy what Thomas is asking. Thanks, i will edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Static variables and method are not inherited, but you can use a static block initializer

```
public class Response {
        public static Response KO_RESPONSE;

        public ReturnCode responseCode;
        public String comment;

        public Response () {};
        public Response (ReturnCode responseCode) {
            this.responseCode = responseCode;
        }

        public static enum ReturnCode {
            OK,
            KO;
        }
    }

    public class DetailResponse extends Response {

        static {
            Response.KO_RESPONSE = new DetailResponse(/* .. */);
        }

        public String otherField;
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If `KO_RESPONSE` is accessed before the class `DetailResponse` is loaded, it will simply be null. Also, note that `KO_RESPONSE` exists only once, so when other subclasses do somehting similar, it is essentially non-deterministic what it contains.

Comment: Further, the field is now `public` but not `final`. Any class could reassign it.

Comment: Im answering the question he is asking. Those problems you mention are design flaws of the given code, which are not my fault

Answer (score -1):

Why you have used A() here, A is not defined.

```
public static final Response KO_RESPONSE = new A(ReturnCode.KO);
```

Detailed response or other type of response can be used here

```
class DetailResponse extends Response {

    public DetailResponse(ReturnCode ko) {
        super(ko);
    }

    public String otherField;
}

class Response {
    public static final Response KO_RESPONSE = new Response(ReturnCode.KO);

    public ReturnCode responseCode;
    public String comment;

    public Response () {};
    public Response (ReturnCode responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public static enum ReturnCode {
        OK,
        KO;
    }
}
```

Also you must have to declare a parameterized constructor for your detailed response class that can be used to defined

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: @bradimus - yes now i understands the point made by Thomas Betous Thanks!